# How to create an AddIn in Autodesk Inventor?

Tags: c#, add-in, autodesk-inventor

I would like to know the procedure for creating an Inventor Add-in using C# or VB.NET. Any settings to be made or how?

I've tried using templates from from various sources, but I got an error. If anyone has successfully done the process, it would be so helpful if you would guide me through it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Any settings to be made or how?" Please explain this question.
Also, please provide the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

I expect you have Inventor (2020) and VisualStudio (2017) installed.

- Install DeveloperTools from SDK (C:\Users\Public\Documents\Autodesk\Inventor 2020\SDK). It creates new project templates to VS. Default template is not perfect, but works.
- Create new project from template "Autodesk Inventor 2020 Addin".
- Go to project properties and remove or disable any post-build action (write EXIT to the first line)
- Compile empty addin.
- See the Readme.txt in the project and follow instructions for register/unregister addin.
- Check that the addin can be loaded. You can use Inventor AddIn manager ("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2020\Bin\AddInMgr.exe"). Find and select your addin in the main window and check that the Location box is not empty.
- Start Inventor and check that your addin is loaded correctly

That's all

Some troubleshooting is described here https://ekinssolutions.com/addins-visualstudio2017/

Answer (score 2):

This is a great resource for learning to create add-ins: [Autodesk University: Creating Add-Ins for Inventor by Brian Ekins (AU Las Vagas 2018)](https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Creating-Add-Ins-Inventor-2018).

He goes in detail into accessing and navigating the API, getting Visual Studio, getting an add-in template for Visual Studio, creating an add-in, and adding commands to it.

Another great resource is the [Inventor API Reference Manual](https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-75023241-53FC-48DB-869F-07E44091DE96). I use this all the time to navigate the API and understand what various methods and properties do. With the "Objects" node expanded, just use Ctrl+F (Find) and type in what you're looking for. Then use the links to navigate backward and find how to access said object.